# Вывод ключей и их значений

Tags: python

```
pizza = {'мука, кг': 1,
         'помидоры, кг': 1.5,
         'шампиньоны, кг': 1.5,
         'сыр, кг': 0.8,
         'оливковое масло, л': 0.1,
         'дрожжи, г': 50}
salad = {'огурцы, кг': 1,
         'перцы, кг': 1,
         'помидоры, кг': 1.5,
         'оливковое масло, л': 0.1,
         'листья салата, кг': 0.4}
  
print_shopping_list(pizza, salad)
```

мой код, возможно, не правильный:

```
def print_shopping_list(list1, list2):
    print(', '.join(set(list1).union(set(list2))))
```

Comment: А зачем объединять словари? Вы же теряете информацию о количестве на дублирующихся ключах.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так вот:

```
pizza = {'мука, кг': 1,
         'помидоры, кг': 1.5,
         'шампиньоны, кг': 1.5,
         'сыр, кг': 0.8,
         'оливковое масло, л': 0.1,
         'дрожжи, г': 50}
salad = {'огурцы, кг': 1,
         'перцы, кг': 1,
         'помидоры, кг': 1.5,
         'оливковое масло, л': 0.1,
         'листья салата, кг': 0.4}

print(dict(pizza, **salad))
```

В питоне 3.9 [добавят](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/) объединение словарей явно и можно будет писать `pizza | salad`

Answer (score 1):

Способов решений данной проблемы много. Ниже представлен метод с использованием chain.from_iterable модуля itertools. Данный метод учитывает, что словари не будут объединены в случае одинаковых ключей в переменных pizza и salad

```
from itertools import chain
izza = {'мука, кг': 1,
         'помидоры, кг': 1.5,
         'шампиньоны, кг': 1.5,
         'сыр, кг': 0.8,
         'оливковое масло, л': 0.1,
         'дрожжи, г': 50}
salad = {'огурцы, кг': 1,
         'перцы, кг': 1,
         'помидоры, кг': 1.5,
         'оливковое масло, л': 0.1,
         'листья салата, кг': 0.4}

foods = chain.from_iterable([pizza.items(), salad.items()])

for food, measure in foods:
    print(food, measure)
```